# Show in real time the users who are viewing a certain record

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have to implement a lightning component in Salesforce that shows, in real-time, the users that are viewing a Case.

How can I implement it?

Comment: I would say that, fundamentally, you cannot do this. You can approximate it, but the detail could easily be incorrect. Viewing a Case is actually just requesting a web page. That's easy enough to detect (you could put a component on the page that generates a "this user viewed case X" entry in the database) but how do you know when the user is no longer viewing that case? You can't really tell since they could do many different actions that effectively remove the case from display - close the browser tab, close the entire browser, click a link on the case page to take them somewhere else etc.

Comment: You can add some assumptions, such as a user keeps a case on display for X minutes and use that to remove the generated "this user viewed case X" entry.

Comment: You should see if Salesforce's Analytics could help.